# Download activity chart flask SQL

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am working on a web application for downloading resources of an unimportant type. It's written in python using the flask web framework. I use the SQLAlchemy DB system.
It has a user authentication system and you can download the resources only while logged in.

What I am trying to do is a download history chart for every resource and every user. To elaborate, each user could see two charts of their download activity on their profile page, for the last 7 days and the last year respectively. Each resource would also have a similar pair of charts, but they would instead visualize how many times the resource itself was downloaded in the time periods.

Here is an example screenshot of the charts
(Don't have enough reputation to embed images)
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5011799/Selection_049.png

The problem is, I can't seem to figure out what the best way to store the downloads in a database would be. I found 2 ways that are relatively easy to implement and should work:

**1)** I could store the download count for each day in the last week in separate fields and every 24 hours just get rid of the first one and move them to the left by 1. This, however, seems like a kind of a hacky way to do this.

**2)** I could also create a separate table for the downloads and every time a user downloads a resource I would insert a row into the table with the Datetime, user_id of the downloader and the resource_id of the downloaded resource. This would allow me to do some nice querying of time periods etc. The problem with that configuration could be the row count in the table. I have no idea how heavily the website is going to be used, but if I do the math with 1000 downloads / day, I am going to end up with over 360k rows in just the first year. I don't know how fast that would to perform. I know I could just archive old entries if performace started being a huge problem.

I would like to know whether the 2nd option would be fast enough for a web app and what configuration you would use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the second approach, with periodic aggregation to improve performance.

Storing counts by day will force you to SELECT the existing count so that you can either add to it with an UPDATE statement or know that you need to INSERT a new record.  That's two trips to the database on every download.  And if things get out of whack, there's really no easy way to determine what happened or what the correct numbers ought to be. (You're not saving information about the individual events.)  That's probably not a significant concern for a simple download count, but if this were sensitive information it might matter.

The second approach simply requires a single INSERT for each download, and because each event is stored separately, it's easy to troubleshoot. And, as you point out, you can slice this data any way you like.

As for performance, 360,000 rows is trivial for a modern RDBMS on contemporary hardware, but you do want to make sure you have an index on date, username/resource name or any other columns that will be used to select data.

Still, you might have more volume than you expect, or maybe your DB is iffy (I'm not familiar with SQLAlchemy).  To reduce your row count you could create a weekly batch process (yeah, I know, batch ain't dead despite what some people say) during non-peak hours to create summary records by week.

It would probably be easiest to create your summary records in a different table that is simply keyed by week and year, or start/end dates, depending on how you want to use it.  After you've generated the weekly summary for a period, you can archive or delete the daily detail records for that period.

Comment: I think I will actually use relationships for the user_id and resource_id, because i have separate tables for users and resources. The aggregation approach seems reasonable. Thanks :)